# How to know whether a remote site using Adobe Flash?

Tags: php, html, flash

I want to know whether a site using  Adobe Flash or not..

$html = file_get_contents($url);
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   @$doc->loadHTML($html);

```
foreach($html->find('embed') as $pageEmbed){
$Count++;
}

foreach($html->find('object') as $pageObject){
$flashTotalCount++;
}

if($Count == 0){  
echo "NO FLASH";    
}   
else{   
echo "FLASH";
}
```

But this code not working any Idea How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api) to detect if Flash is installed

```
if (swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("11.0")) {
  // has Flash
}
else {
  // no Flash
}
```